# Extend desktop between Windows7 and Windows 11 with HDMI cable

Tags: windows, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have two laptops, one with windows 11 and the other one with windows 7; my goal is to extend the desktop of windows 11 monitor on the other monitor. Is it possible to do it? I have both connected with HDMI cable?